# Does a player become immune to the Magician when getting murdered or robbed?

Tags: citadels

We are wondering if a killed or robbed character is immune to the Magician or not.
Can the Magician force to swap district cards with a player who has been assassinated or robbed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Magician targets a player, not a role, so I don't see why the fact they were targeted by the Assassin/Witch would have any impact on this.

Comment: Because it's so sad to see someone getting killed or robbed then you swap its cards and to finish you swap a district lol

Answer (score 7):

Further to bwarner's answer:

Not only are the players **not immune**, but there's no way you could even make them immune based on the other rules of the game.

The assassination target isn't revealed until the round is finished. Until then, you can't know for certain whether someone has been assassinated or not. For the magician to know this, the assassinated player would have to reveal early.

This is similar with the thief. Unless the thief stole from the magician, the thief won't yet know if they've hit or not.